# How to separate gene names joined by underscore?

Tags: sed, replace, text-formatting, bioinformatics

I would like to separate gene names that were joined by dash. I would like to replace by tabs.

My input file is:

```
Cedr3g0570.1_XP_019283.1
Cedr4g7930.2_XP_019241.1
Cedr5g005170.1_C0LGS3.1
Cedr7g0290.5_XP_01921.1
CT35v5_contig_2082_1.6_XP_0272.1
CT35v5_Cedr2g060.1_GAU97.1
CT7New_004.1_XP_01996.1
```

But I would like the follow output:

```
Cedr3g0570.1            XP_019283.1
Cedr4g7930.2            XP_019241.1
Cedr5g005170.1          C0LGS3.1
Cedr7g0290.5            XP_01921.1
CT35v5_contig_2082_1.6  XP_0272.1
CT35v5_Cedr2g060.1      GAU97.1
CT7New_004.1            XP_01996.1
```

The issue is that I cannot simple replace the first dash because I have some genes with dash in their names, such as CT35v5_contig_2082_1.6.
I tried to use `sed 's/_/\t/'` but it did not work for some genes, such as CT35v5_contig_2082_1.6

Comment: it is after the .* such as ".1", ".2", ".5"  etc.

Comment: Looks like the pattern would be the first instance of \.[0-9]_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sed 's/\(\.[0-9]\)\(_\)/\1 /' inputfile | column -t
```

The regular expression `/\.[0-9]_/` appears to match your case, so I split that into two backreference groups using parens, and print the first group and some whitespace, thereby separating your columns, which can then be tabularized using `column -t`.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't quite see the point of the second group.

Comment: The second grouping is somewhat superfluous and can probably be discarded:  `'s/\(\.[0-9]\)_/\1 /'`

Answer (score 2):

It appears the underscore you want to replace is ALWAYS after a dot `.` followed by a single digit `[0-9]`.

```
sed 's|\.\([0-9]\)_|.\1\t|'
```

This will search for a literal dot `\.`followed by a single digit which we'll save in a group `\([0-9]\)` followed by an underscore `_`. Replace that with a dot, the first group we saved `\1` and a tab `\t`.